# VBA Selenium Edge open website based on class

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to navigate to a website based on what class name can be found. Based on the given ID it opens the first website and searches for 1 of 3 different class names. Based on what class name matches I want to open a specific website. The first website always has 1 of 3 different class names. With my current code when VBA does not find the very first class name it give me the error "Element not found" and does not continue to ElseIf. If first class name is found then it works fine and gives no errors. How can I make VBA ignore this error or make it search for all 3 class names and decide what to do based on what class name was found?

Code:

```
    Dim appME As New WebDriver
    appME.Start "edge", ""
    Dim id
    id = 141765
      
    appME.Get "website 1" & id
    
    If (Not appME.FindElementByClass("Class1") Is Nothing) Then
         appME.Get "website 2" & id
    ElseIf (Not appME.FindElementByClass("Class2") Is Nothing) Then
         appME.Get "website 3" & id
    ElseIf (Not appME.FindElementByClass("Class3") Is Nothing) Then
         appME.Get "website 4" & id
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding Raise:=False after classname.

```
Dim appME As New WebDriver
    appME.Start "edge", ""
    Dim id
    id = 141765
      
    appME.Get "website 1" & id
    
    If (Not appME.FindElementByClass("Class1", Raise:=False) Is Nothing) Then
         appME.Get "website 2" & id
    ElseIf (Not appME.FindElementByClass("Class2", Raise:=False) Is Nothing) Then
         appME.Get "website 3" & id
    ElseIf (Not appME.FindElementByClass("Class3", Raise:=False) Is Nothing) Then
         appME.Get "website 4" & id
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add `On Error Resume Next` before calling `FindElementByClass`, and `On Error GoTo 0` afterwards.

To make sure an error in `appME.Get` does not get masked, it will probably be best to put this into a function of its own:

```
   Function MyFindElementByClass(appME as WebDriver, Byval classname as String) as WebElement
       Set MyFindElementByClass=Nothing
       On Error Resume Next
       Set MyFindElementByClass=appME.FindElementByClass(classname)
       On Error Goto 0
   End Function
```

Comment: Still a beginner with coding. What you suggest is create a function for each class name?
How do I then instruct VBA to check which class name exists and open one of 3 websites?

Comment: @AurisxD: No, I suggest you create a wrapper for `FindElementByClass` which does not stop with an error, but returns Nothing instead. `classname` is just a string parameter.

Comment: Still strugling to make my code work. From your suggestion this is what I should do but I get Argument not optional error.
```
Function Technical(appME As WebDriver, ByVal Menu1_mnuMain_3 As String) As WebElement
        Set Technical = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Technical = appME.FindElementByClass("Menu1_mnuMain_3")
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Function
If (Not Technical Is Nothing) Then 'Error here
            appME.Get "website" & id
```